# Lightning Out Site returns guest records only

Tags: apex, lightning

I have an issue displaying SOQL records on the lightning out component.

If the component is accessed through Salesforce (with an active session) i retrieve all the opportunities on the page. However if the component is accessed through the site as a guest user, only records that are created by guest users are shown.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page id="lightningouttest" showHeader="false">
<apex:includeLightning />

<div id="lightning" />

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:formApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:formOpportunity",
            {},
            "lightning",
            function(cmp) {


            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Lightning App:

```
<aura:application description="formApp" access="global"  
extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">

<aura:dependency resource="c:formOpportunity" type="COMPONENT"/>

</aura:application>
```

Component:

```
<aura:component description="formOpportunity" controller="formApexController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:handler value="{!this}" name="init" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:attribute name="oppo" type="Opportunity[]"/>

<lightning:card title="Opportunities">
    <c:addOpportunity />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.oppo}" var="o">
    <lightning:card iconName="standard:contact">
    <aura:set attribute="title">
        <a href="{! '/' + o.Id}" >{!o.Name}</a>
    </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:iteration>
</lightning:card>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class formApexController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunity(Id opportunityId){

    List<Opportunity> o = [select id,Name from opportunity];

    return o;

}
}
```

Comment: Can you make your class without sharing ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava lol that really worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring 18 has a [critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_apex_implicit_sharing_keyword_cruc.htm) to fix this issue .If your apex class version is not 41 and prior the default behavior for classes without or with sharing was to use with sharing .

With current release this is fixed to use without sharing for all classes which does not specify without or with sharing keyword .

However as a best practice mark your apex class without sharing to skip the sharing rules of the platform for aura enabled methods. In this case mark your apex explicitly to use without sharing.